# How to use find_element_by_class_name when there are several values with the same class name?

Tags: python, web-scraping

I'm new to web scraping and have run into two problems. First, when I try to use find_element_by_class_name, I get an error that find_element_by_* commands are deprecated. Another issue I'm having is that the website I am trying to web scrape has multiple values assigned to the same class. How can I ensure that I'm retrieving the correct information from the website?

```
s=Service("C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=s)
driver.get("https://covidactnow.org/us/california-ca/county/sacramento_county/?s=26811580")
print(driver.title)

search = driver.find_element_by_class_name("sc-pAzCb jEBzr")
print(search)
```

[image: This is the class and content I am trying to retrieve]

[image: But the same class stores different values on different parts of the website]

The first picture shows the class and content I am trying to retrieve. But as the second screenshot shows, the same class stores different values on different parts of the website. How do I differntiate between the two?

Comment: You cannot distinguish between the two (or more) occurrences. From your sample HTML the same classes occur in the same element type (span). It may be that you can determine which one is relevant to you by the order in which they are observed

Answer (score 0):

Why not just go to the API the webpage uses to get the data?

All you need to do is get the list of paths e.g. https://data.covidactnow.org/snapshot/2688/v2/state/AL.timeseries.json for a state or https://data.covidactnow.org/snapshot/2688/v2/county/06067.timeseries.json for a county.

You can get a list of paths for the states and counties by cutting the relevant JSON from https://covidactnow.org/static/js/main.bcbf2cb9.chunk.js